# How to pass information between GUI callbacks

Tags: matlab

I want to pass queryname which is a string and resembles full path of an image to another file do_demo_2.

```
function query_browse_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname] = ...
uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png';'*.tif'},'Select Query Image');
queryname=[pathname filename];

function retrieve_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
do_demo_2;
```

how should i modify this and what would be my 1st line in do_demo_2 file??

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass data around in a GUI, it is most convenient to store the data in the `handles`-structure. Choose either version 1 or version 2 (they are not inter-compatible).

```
function query_browse_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname] = ...
uigetfile({'*.jpg';'*.png';'*.tif'},'Select Query Image');
queryname=[pathname filename];

%# store queryname, version 1
handles.queryname = queryname;
guidata(hObject,handles);
%# store queryname, version 2
setappdata(handles.YOURGUINAME,'queryname',queryname)


function retrieve_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

%# retrieve queryname, version 1
queryname = handles.queryname;
%# retrieve queryname, version 2
queryname = getappdata(handles.YOURGUINAME,'queryname');
```

Make sure that in the `Opening_Fcn` of your GUI, you initialize the stored information:

```
%# version 1
handles.queryname = '';
guidata(hObject,handles);

%# version 2
setappdata(handles.YOURGUINAME,'queryname','');
```

This way, you can check in `retrieve_callback` whether `queryname` is empty and tell the user to browse for a filename first.

If you then want to pass the contents of queryname to a different function, you pass it as an input argument: `do_demo_2(queryname)`. Make sure the function accepts inputs.

Comment: How should i define the function to pass "queryname" in do_demo_2 file?

Comment: Well the !st version doesnt work and for the second version i get an error "Reference to non-existent field 'query_gui" where query_gui is my gui name

Comment: @user1533956: ok, there was a typo in version 1, which has been fixed now. I have added some more information on initializing the storage etc.

Comment: Ok It works...but the  problem is i am passing a string value and it is accepting as char...plz help!!

Comment: @user1533956: sorry, what are you passing where? Also, a string is just a char array, and since in Matlab, everything is an array, there is not really a difference between char and string.

Comment: I passed queryname in do_demo_2 and there is a function in that file "imreadbw"which uses queryname as string but i am getting this error now "Undefined function or method 'imreadbw' for input arguments of type 'char'."

Comment: @user1533956: "undefined function or method xxx" usually occurs when the function `xxx` is not found on the path. Since `imreadbw` is not a built-in Matlab function, make sure that you download it and/or make it visible on the path. Search on this site for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+undefined+function

Comment: Jonas i am really very happy that you helping me but the code was working fine before and the function is in the same folder...sorry to bother you so much :(

Comment: What the error means is that the fuction cant take input arguments of type char which means the "queryname" has changed to char...how can i convert it to string again???

Comment: I am doing my college project on "image retrieval using sift"...can you plz tell me if it is necessary to use hough transform and best-bin-first in that?...i have managed to gt the sift code from net...stuck with the latter part..:(

Comment: @user1533956: As I am unfamiliar with SIFT (it doesn't work on the type of images I usually work with), I cannot help you with that question.